# When eth contract function need return value with storage? and why not just with memory type?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I am learning the source code for [gnosis/safe-contracts](https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/2620a21c0844f23df39ea98438b82e378bb334f0/contracts/examples/guards/ReentrancyTransactionGuard.sol#L21). For this example file, I have a question about, why this function need return a data with *storage*, I know the difference between *storage* and *memory*.

```
/*
 *https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/2620a21c0844f23df39ea98438b82e378bb334f0/contracts/examples/guards/ReentrancyTransactionGuard.sol#L21
 */
function getGuard() internal pure returns (GuardValue storage guard) {
    bytes32 slot = GUARD_STORAGE_SLOT;
    // solhint-disable-next-line no-inline-assembly
    assembly {
        guard.slot := slot
    }
}
```

A more general question is maybe about the return value when we need or must use *storage*? Is there any doc can I refer to? really Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is invoked from `checkTransaction()` where it sets the `guard` property `active`.

```
GuardValue storage guard = getGuard();
require(!guard.active, "Reentrancy detected");
guard.active = true;
```

If `getGuard()` returned a memory variable (instead of a storage one), the `guard` variable would need to be a memory variable as well - otherwise you'd have a mismatch trying to assign memory variable into a storage one, which wouldn't compile.

And if the `guard` variable had a memory location, it would change the `active` value only in the memory copy, not in the actual storage.

TLDR: A storage pointer allows to change the value in the persistent storage. A memory variable is "just" a non-persistent copy of the storage value.

Comment: Really, thank you. I have already created a simple demo for the test. By the way, could you help me with another QA. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71898608/how-can-eth-contract-replay-attacks-be-prevented-and-detected